# How to bind/register the User of the current http request with a class

Tags: asp.net-core, autofac, asp.net-core-1.1

With Autofac using Web Api 2 I could bind the current http request instance to a certain c# class.

How can I do this with asp.net core without autofac just using the

```
IServiceCollection services
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can register `IHttpContextAccessor` and inject this into your services

```
services.AddSingleton<IHttpContextAccessor, HttpContextAccessor>();
```

then you can access the HttpContext via `httpContextAccessor.HttpContext`.

Comment: thanks, found it now too :P https://www.strathweb.com/2016/12/accessing-httpcontext-outside-of-framework-components-in-asp-net-core/